# Number of bounded functions $\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ given start and end points

Tags: combinatorics

Denote $[n]=\{0,1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$. For fixed $m,n$, I am trying to calculate the number functions $f:[n]\to \mathbb Z$ which satisfies the following properties:

- $f(k+1)-f(k)=1 \text{ or}-1, \forall k$.
- $f(k)\ge 0$ for all $k$.
- $f(n-1)=m-1$, $f(0)=0$.

I try to use an inductive process to reduce the problem to some "base" case. However, I find that it is necessary to have $f(k)\geq r$ for non-zero integer values of $r$. In the end, I fail to obtain a formula.

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Henry Yes. Sorry for missing it.

Comment: You can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much!